# Is there a YUI3 plugin similar to RoutesJS to accept user input from in the URL that could trigger some events in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, yui, yui3

Looked around but I think I may have missed it as I'm not a veteran YUI library user.

This is what I'm looking for or something similar on YUI's side, preferably in YUI3: http://routesjs.com

Answer (score 1):

Right now there isn't anything in YUI 3 that's exactly the same as jQuery Routes, but the YUI 3 History module can be used to achieve similar behavior (just not via a route-based API): http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/history/

I plan to implement a route-based API on top of History in a future version of YUI (probably 3.4.0).

Answer (score 1):

YUI 3.4 PR2 has an 'app' module that offers similar functionality. There aren't any browseable API docs for it yet, since 3.4 isn't formally release, but you can peruse the inline documentation in the source [here](https://github.com/yui/yui3/blob/master/build/app/app.js). 3.4 should be cooked by the end of the summer, and the 'app' module is considered feature-complete at this point.

Comment: Of course I didn't bother to check the author of the first answer. Ryan is the implementor of the YUI app module. :)